# При выводе приложения в эмулятор, черный экран без данных

Tags: android, viewmodel

В приложении использую API и JSON с [сайта](https://www.themoviedb.org/)
После добавления зависимостей (ViewModel, LifeCycle, Room) в build.gradle в строку:

```
dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

def lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"
def arch_version = "2.1.0"

// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"
// Lifecycles only (without ViewModel or LiveData)
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:$lifecycle_version"


// Saved state module for ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

// Annotation processor
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
// alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of lifecycle-compiler
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

// optional - helpers for implementing LifecycleOwner in a Service
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"

// optional - ProcessLifecycleOwner provides a lifecycle for the whole application process
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"

// optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:$lifecycle_version"

// optional - Test helpers for LiveData
testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version"

def room_version = "2.2.6"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

// optional - RxJava support for Room
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"

// optional - Guava support for Room, including Optional and ListenableFuture
implementation "androidx.room:room-guava:$room_version"

// optional - Test helpers
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
}
```

не могу определить в MainActivity элемент viewModel c ViewModelProviders(пишет почему-то перечеркнутым текстом, выдает только ViewModelProvider почему-то):

```
private MainViewModel viewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
```

[image: screen_1]

Интерфейс MovieDao и классы MovieDatabase, MainViewModel созданы и прописаны.
После сборки приложения в эмуляторе появляется черный экран без каких-либо данных (остались только переключатели switch и textView). Хотя до этого всё отлично выводилось и переключалось. Что это может быть и в чем проблема? Помогите решить данную проблему, пожалуйста.

Comment: приложите пожалуйста код в виде отформатированного текста, а так же разметку проблемного экрана

Comment: @Andrew ссылка на файлы с кодом и разметкой: https://transfiles.ru/qhu10

Comment: тут немного другие правила) код в вопрос добавьте пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Ну типо ViewModelProviders это просто deprecated и поэтому оно перечеркивается. но я так использую и нормально, но лучше конечно по новому делать ([[в документаций можешь посмотреть](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0-alpha03)][1](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#2.2.0-alpha03) там где API Changes)

Comment: Ок, с этим понятно. А черный экран то как исправить?)

Comment: можешь показать свой метод по добавлению фильмов в adapter или просто сам проверь там должен в конце вызываться метод notifyDataSetChanged(), если не это то можешь показать весь код adapter и MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, вопрос решен. Была ошибка символа в методе при проверке получения данных JSON в MainActivity.